# Why is my drive axle clunking when I first accelerate or release the pedal?

Tags: axle, cv-joint

I recently replaced my drive axles and my passenger side clunks when I first accelerate or decelerate. It also clunks when I let it coast at a low speed. Pushing on my brake stops it. I'm thinking it can be two things. It's possible that I didn't push it in all the way, I'm going to try and tap it in a bit more. Although I'm wondering if it's possible that I could have ruined it while installing. I was trying to pull it out so that I could put it back in properly and I ended up making the inner cv joint get stuck. I moved the drive axle around a bit and it seemed to be fine but I later read that might ruin the drive axle.

Update: it's hammered in all the way, is it possible to ruin the cv joint by pulling it?

Comment: How did the inner joint get stuck? Do you mean it wasn't fully seated and was binding? The cv joints can be pulled apart and put back together. If you were driving on it and the joint wasn't fully seated it may have been damaged. You could pull the boot off and check or just warranty the whole assembly if it's a concern. Are you sure the axle nut is torqued to spec? That can also cause noise. Brake pads are moving freely in the bracket? Rattle clips are in place?

Comment: I'll check the brake pad but the axle nut is torqued to spec. The joint was fully seated while I was driving on it, it just became unseated while installing and I was concerned that would ruin the joint.

Comment: The inner CV joint got stuck when I pulled in the center part of the axle while it was pretty snugly connected on the other side of the inner CV joint. I then pulled it the center axle back again and was able to align it and cause it to go back to normal.

Comment: I doubt the joints themselves are damaged. If you jack up the front of the car and spin it by hand can you reproduce the clunking?

Comment: I'll try that in a few hours when I can, thank you very much for the help. Do you suppose it might be something else? It sounds just like the clunking that was happening on my old CV joints. It's only on the right side now though. It also only happens while lightly accelerating and decelerating and driving very slowly(stop and go traffic). I want to warranty it if that's the problem.

Comment: Mine does this too. Started right after changing right axle. They couldnt get it back out either.
I wonder if it involves the seating of that c ring in a groove.
Feel it thru floor. When front end up in air the wheel play noise matches area and tone frkm right side of transmission

Comment: @ShaneBird what's the verdict on this one, were you able to reproduce by hand? Would be great to mount a camera to the subframe somehow and record the behavior.

Comment: Couple questions: New or reman CVs? Also, are you sure you tightened up the other suspension bolts, specifically ball joints and possibly struts, when you reassembled?

Answer (score 0):

What year and make is it? Did you replace both sides? It may be the inner joints are not fully seated or they are misaligned, from falling apart. Did you tighten the axle nut with the tire on sitting on the ground or tire off up in the air stopping from turning while someone was smashing the brake pedal? It may even be where the outer joint goes through the hub if it was not aligned and seated.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be your axle. When you removed the ball joint mount or strut hardware to get the driveshaft out, are you sure you re-tightened all bolts after the car was sitting on the ground and that the strut top bearing is in good shape and installed in the right direction? Stabilizer bar and bushing mounts all tight?

Comment: Or ,engine mount.